# ruby web-scraping tool scrubyt error:- kernel_require.rb:112:in `require': cannot load such file -- jcode (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize, scrubyt

I am running a web scraping script using scrubyt web scraping too. When I run then script I get above error.
Below is the full trace:-

```
vishnu-suman@vishnusuman:~/ror$ ruby scrubyt1.rb
/home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3/gems/scrubyt-0.4.06/lib/scrubyt.rb:1: warning: variable $KCODE is no longer effective; ignored
/home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require': cannot load such file -- jcode (LoadError)
  from /home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
  from /home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3/gems/scrubyt-0.4.06/lib/scrubyt.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `require'
  from /home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:116:in `rescue in require'
  from /home/vishnu-suman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
  from scrubyt1.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I googled a lot but couldn't find any solution. NOT even on stackoverflow.
I will provide you if you need more information.
I will appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to remove line `require 'jcode'` from `scrubyt.rb` file.

Comment: Scrubyt? Never heard of it. My advice? Get rid of it.

Comment: I tried it after removing but still same problem. Can you advise me any web scraping tool based on ruby which can able to scrape JavaScript and ajax based web pages? I was using Mechanize but it's not able to scrap JS and ajax based pages. Any advise will be much appreciated. Thank you